# ActiveRecord - how to create a scope on the MIN and MAX of a `has_many` children relationship?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I have a relationship as follows:

```rb
class Trip < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trip_destinations, dependent: :destroy
end

class TripDestination < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trip
  
  validates :start_date, presence: true
  validates :end_date, presence: true
end
```

I want to write a query that returns **all trips where the `MIN(trip_destinations.start_date)` is before `Date.today` but the `MAX(trip_destinations.end_date)` is after `Date.today`**; that is, `Trip` still has `TripDestination`s that start before today AND end after today.

### Debugging so far:

Currently, what I have is:

```rb
    Trip
      .joins(:trip_destinations)
      .where("
        trip_destinations.start_date = (
          SELECT MIN(trip_destinations.start_date) FROM trip_destinations
             WHERE trips.id = trip_destinations.trip_id
        )
        AND trip_destinations.start_date <= ?", today
      )
      .where("
        trip_destinations.end_date = (
          SELECT MAX(trip_destinations.end_date) FROM trip_destinations
             WHERE trips.id = trip_destinations.trip_id
        )
        AND trip_destinations.end_date > ?", today
      )
      .group("trips.id")
```

Outputed SQL:

```
      SELECT 1 AS one FROM "trips" INNER JOIN "trip_destinations" ON "trip_destinations"."trip_id" = "trips"."id" WHERE "trips"."published" = $1 AND (
        trip_destinations.start_date = (
          SELECT MIN(trip_destinations.start_date) FROM trip_destinations
             WHERE trips.id = trip_destinations.trip_id
        )
        AND trip_destinations.start_date <= '2022-11-08') AND (
        trip_destinations.end_date = (
          SELECT MAX(trip_destinations.end_date) FROM trip_destinations
             WHERE trips.id = trip_destinations.trip_id
        )
        AND trip_destinations.end_date > '2022-11-08') GROUP BY "trips"."id" LIMIT $2  [["published", true], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

which returns an empty set `[]`, even though I've manually verified that a `Trip` exists of this nature.

What's more, I can **break down the SQL query in to the component `WHERE` clauses and they both work independently**.
i.e.

```rb
    Trip
      .joins(:trip_destinations)
      .where("
        trip_destinations.start_date = (
          SELECT MIN(trip_destinations.start_date) FROM trip_destinations
             WHERE trips.id = trip_destinations.trip_id
        )
        AND trip_destinations.start_date <= ?", today
      )
```

Returns the trip, and also

```rb
    Trip
      .joins(:trip_destinations)
      .where("
        trip_destinations.end_date = (
          SELECT MAX(trip_destinations.end_date) FROM trip_destinations
             WHERE trips.id = trip_destinations.trip_id
        )
        AND trip_destinations.end_date > ?", today
      )
```

returns the trip. However, when I chain those `WHERE` together, for some reason `ActiveRecord` or `Postgres` don't like it.

It's probably worth noting too, that I don't need to include the `start_date <= ?` for this to break.

```rb
    Trip
      .joins(:trip_destinations)
      .where("
        trip_destinations.start_date = (
          SELECT MIN(trip_destinations.start_date) FROM trip_destinations
             WHERE trips.id = trip_destinations.trip_id
        )
      )
      .where("
        trip_destinations.end_date = (
          SELECT MAX(trip_destinations.end_date) FROM trip_destinations
             WHERE trips.id = trip_destinations.trip_id
        )
      )
      .group("trips.id")
```

also returns an empty set.

### Desired outcome

A single query (subqueries are fine) which returns all `Trip` records that have at least one `TripDestination` with a `start_date <= Date.today` and `end_date > Date.today`

Comment: @engineersmnky because a `Trip` can have multiple `trip_destination`s. For instance, let's say that you have `[<TripDestination start_date: Date.yesterday end_date: Date.tomorrow>, <TripDestination start_date: Date.tomorrow + 1.day, end_date: Date.tomorrow + 2.days>` that `Trip` would be "in progress".

The total "length" of the `Trip` would be `Date.yesterday...Date.tomorrow + 2.days` as you'd need to aggregate all the children's lengths.
Hence you'd want the minimum `start_date` and maximum `end_date` for _all_ the children of the `Trip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am still not certain exactly why the following does not resolve the issue

```
Trip
  .joins(:trip_destinations)
  .where(trip_destinations: {start_date: ..Date.today, end_date: Date.today...})
```

This will satisfy the actual desire stated: *"returns all `Trip` records that have at least one `TripDestination` with a `start_date <= Date.today` and `end_date > Date.today`"*

But if your true desire is *"return all `Trip` records that have a `TripDestination` where the first `start_date` is less than or equal to today and the last `end_date` is greater than today"* then you could instead use a HAVING clause with aggregate functions as follows:

```
 Trip
   .joins(:trip_destinations)
   .group(:id) 
   .having( 
      TripDestination.arel_table[:start_date].minimum.lteq(Date.today).and(
       TripDestination.arel_table[:end_date].maximum.gt(Date.today))
   )
```

SQL generated:

```
SELECT 
  trips.* 
FROM 
  trips
  INNER JOIN trip_destinations ON trip_destinations.trip_id = trips.id 
GROUP BY 
  trips.id 
HAVING 
  MIN(trip_destinations.start_date) <= '2022-11-08' AND 
  MAX(trip_destinations.end_date) > '2022-11-08'
```

This solution assumes PostgreSQL or MySQL (with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled). If this is not the case then you could go with

```
Trip.where(id: 
  Trip 
    .select(:id)
    .joins(:trip_destinations)
    .group(:id) 
    .having( 
      TripDestination.arel_table[:start_date].minimum.lteq(Date.today).and(
       TripDestination.arel_table[:end_date].maximum.gt(Date.today))
   )
)
```

Resulting SQL:

```
SELECT 
  trips.* 
FROM 
  trips 
WHERE 
  trips.id IN ( 
    SELECT 
      trips.id 
    FROM 
      trips
      INNER JOIN trip_destinations ON trip_destinations.trip_id = trips.id 
    GROUP BY 
      trips.id 
    HAVING 
      MIN(trip_destinations.start_date) <= '2022-11-08' AND 
      MAX(trip_destinations.end_date) > '2022-11-08' 
)
```

Comment: Hey! The `HAVING` clause is exactly what I'm looking for! I'll mask your question as the correct answer, but I was wondering if you could clearly mark the second `HAVING` SQL as the correct answer in this case?

Thanks so much!

Comment: For some more context as well, the first SQL you posted actually didn't return the correct `Trip` object either.

Comment: @JahSengLee glad it worked for you. Maybe I am missing something but from what I can see there is only 1 reason the first solution would not return the correct `Trip` and that is when `end_date = Date.today` and `end_date` does not equal `MAX(end_date)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried merging the two where clauses into one like so ?

```
Trip.joins(:trip_destinations)
    .where(
      "(
        trip_destinations.start_date = (
          SELECT MIN(trip_destinations.start_date) FROM trip_destinations WHERE trips.id = trip_destinations.trip_id
        )
        AND trip_destinations.start_date <= ?
      ) AND
      (
        trip_destinations.end_date = (
          SELECT MAX(trip_destinations.end_date) FROM trip_destinations WHERE trips.id = trip_destinations.trip_id
        )
        AND trip_destinations.end_date > ?
      )", today, today
    )
```

Comment: Yup, that was actually my first attempt. Alas, no records returned

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that the desired outcome is : A single query (subqueries are fine) which returns all Trip records that have at least one TripDestination with a start_date <= Date.today and end_date > Date.today

Can try this scope ?

```rb
  scope :strict, -> {
      distinct
      .joins(:trip_destinations)
      .where(trip_destinations: {
        start_date: ..DateTime.now.beginning_of_day
      })
      .where('trip_destinations.end_date > ?', DateTime.now.end_of_day )
  }
```